# Navicat Lite dump functionality

Tags: mysql, database

Does [Navicat Lite](http://www.navicat.com/en/download/download.html) have an "advanced options" section (or something to that effect)?

I'd like to specify options such as "neglect" or "do not drop" and "create table".

Comment: IIRC, that's the reason it's *Lite*: it's nice, but lacks the advanced functionality of the full (paid) version. As a happy user, I'd recommend the full version.

Comment: You can always go to the source for that functionality and use the pg_dump tool. Or, use an alternative to Navicat like pgAdmin3.

Comment: Use another tool or buy the premium version.